# Encode string "aaa" to "3[a]"

Tags: string, algorithm

give a string s, encode it by the format: "aaa" to "3[a]". The length of encoded string should the shortest.
example: "abbabb" to "2[a2[b]]"

update: suppose the string only contains lowercase letters

update: here is my code in c++, but it's slow. I know one of the improvement is using KMP to compute if the current string is combined by a repeat string.

```
// this function is used to check if a string is combined by repeating a substring. 
// Also Here can be replaced by doing KMP algorithm for whole string to improvement

bool checkRepeating(string& s, int l, int r, int start, int end){  
    if((end-start+1)%(r-l+1) != 0)
        return false;
    int len = r-l+1;
    bool res = true;
    for(int i=start; i<=end; i++){
        if(s[(i-start)%len+l] != s[i]){
            res = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

// this function is used to get the length of the current number
int getLength(int l1, int l2){
    return (int)(log10(l2/l1+1)+1);
}

string shortestEncodeString(string s){
    int len = s.length();

    vector< vector<int> > res(len, vector<int>(len, 0));
    //Initial the matrix 
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
            res[j][i] = i-j+1;
        }
    }

    unordered_map<string, string> record;

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        for(int j=i; j>=0; j--){

            string temp = s.substr(j, i-j+1);
/* if the current substring has showed before, then no need to compute again
 * Here is a example for this part: if the string is "abcabc".
 * if we see the second "abc", then no need to compute again, just use the
 * result from first "abc".
**/
            if(record.find(temp) != record.end()){
                res[j][i] = record[temp].size();
                continue;
            }
            string ans = temp;
            for(int k=j; k<i; k++){

                string str1 = s.substr(j, k-j+1);
                string str2 = s.substr(k+1, i-k);
                if(res[j][i] > res[j][k] + res[k+1][i]){
                    res[j][i] = res[j][k]+res[k+1][i];
                    ans = record[str1] + record[str2];
                }

                if(checkRepeating(s, j, k, k+1, i) == true && res[j][i] > 2+getLength(k-j+1, i-k)+res[j][k]){
                    res[j][i] = 2+getLength(k-j+1, i-k)+res[j][k];
                    ans = to_string((i-j+1)/(k-j+1)) + '[' + record[str1] +']';
                }
            }
            record[temp] = ans;
        }

    }

    return record[s];
}
```

Comment: I tried a greedy solution. but the complexity is very bad. Try the string from index 0 with length 1,2,3... and then find the index that this substring doesn't repeat and then call the function with the rest of the string. and also do the same the prefix string with len 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Okay, edit your code into the question, if you want someone to help you troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

With very little to start with in terms of a question statement, I took a quick stab at this using JavaScript because it's easy to demonstrate. The comments are in the code, but basically there are alternating stages of joining adjacent elements, run-length checking, joining adjacent elements, and on and on until there is only one element left - the final encoded value.

[image: quick algorithm sketch]

I hope this helps.

```js
function encode(str) {
  var tmp = str.split('');
  var arr = [];

  do {
    if (tmp.length === arr.length) {
      // Join adjacent elements
      arr.length = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i += 2) {
        if (i < tmp.length - 1) {
          arr.push(tmp[i] + tmp[i + 1]);
        } else {
          arr.push(tmp[i]);
        }
      }
      tmp.length = 0;
    } else {
      // Swap arrays and clear tmp
      arr = tmp.slice();
      tmp.length = 0;
    }

    // Build up the run-length strings
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
      var runlength = runLength(arr, i);
      if (runlength > 1) {
        tmp.push(runlength + '[' + arr[i] + ']');
      } else {
        tmp.push(arr[i]);
      }
      i += runlength;
    }
    console.log(tmp);
  } while (tmp.length > 1);
  return tmp.join();
}

// Get the longest run length from a given index
function runLength(arr, ind) {
  var count = 1;
  for (var i = ind; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i + 1] === arr[ind]) {
      count++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

```html
<input id='inp' value='abbabb'>
<button type="submit" onClick='javascript:document.getElementById("result").value=encode(document.getElementById("inp").value)'>Encode</button>
<br>
<input id='result' value='2[a2[b]]'>
```